# mysql showing different number of databases

Tags: mysql, terminal

This is from my terminal in mac.

```
130-229-0-129-dhcp:~ suyeshamatya$ mysql


mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> quit
Bye
130-229-0-129-dhcp:~ suyeshamatya$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| lportal            |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can someone please explain why mysql is showing different number of databases when connecting without any **username/password** and when connecting with **root** **username/password**?

**UPDATE:**

Connected without username/password

```
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Connected with root username/password

```
mysql> show grants;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '********************' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grant **USAGE** means no privileges for that user according to [**Manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage). So when you login without **username** and **password**. It will show default mysql schema. If you want to user using following query:

```
select User from mysql.user;
```

It will throw error like

```
SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user';
```

Which means you do not have permission on default database to view users details.

If you login with username and password then all the databases created by that User will show you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think that the the "unknown user" has no privileges to see the other databases. Please check this in the mysql database.